# Error with Powershell Workflow in Automation Account foreach -parallel

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-workflow

I have issues publishing a PowerShell workflow. Most of the script I am using is run in sequence, including the first for loop. But I would like to final for loop to execute in parallel. The code is as follows:

```
workflow myWorkflow {
code..
code..
regular for loop
   foreach -parallel
}
myWorkflow
```

An error occured while publishing the runbook 'myWorkflow'.
Error details:
The Runbook definition is invalid. The '-parallel' parameter can be used only within a workflow.
The Runbook definition must contain only one definition which is workflow.. Error code: BadRequest..

The code runs very slow otherwise. Is there an issue with my code or the setup of the script?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right syntax for your [parallel block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_parallel?view=powershell-5.1)? Also, workflows are expected to be slow, even in parallel. They're meant for long running scripts.

Comment: a long running script for me is something that could take 4+ hours. I'll play around with the parallel block, I don't have much experience with workflows to begin with. thank you!

Comment: Right my point was, is it really needed a workflow?